# Is there a Visual Studio Code extension that will write cucumber step definitions?

Tags: intellij-idea, visual-studio-code, cucumber, auto-generate

Is there a Visual Studio Code extension that will write cucumber step definitions?

For example, with IntelliJ if I type

```
When I login as "fred" with password "barney"
```

into a feature, then press alt-enter on the undefined step, IntelliJ will auto-generate

```
When(/^I login as "([^"]*)" with password "([^"]*)"$/) do |arg1, arg2|
  pending
end
```

in one of my step definition files.

Can Visual Studio Code do this also?  (I do have Cucumber Full Support installed; but, it seems to only autocomplete existing steps.)

Answer (score 2):

So far as I see Cucumebr VS Code extension does not provides auto-generation/update of test steps as IntelliJ or SpecFlow.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use the SpecFlow plugin from [SpecFlow](https://specflow.org/) and it will automatically generate all your cucumber feature steps.

Comment: It's a **visual studio** extension, not a **visual studio code** extension.

Answer (score 1):

Try Jest cucumber for auto-generation of code from feature file-
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Piotr-Porzuczek.jest-cucumber-code-generator-extension

Comment: Links can become invalid in the future, consider adding some quotations from the link you posted, and then refer to it

Answer (score -1):

There is [Cucumber (Gherkin) Full Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=alexkrechik.cucumberautocomplete) plugin. It has auto-completion of steps, as well as many other features.

Comment: Does it have auto-generation of step files as OP is asking for?

Comment: OP is not asking for auto-generation of step files.

Comment: Can you please re-read the question and verify? sounds to me like he is asking for auto-generation of step definitions rather than auto-completion.

Comment: "in one of my step definition files" - step definition files are there, step definition themselves are missing.

Comment: So does this extension generate step definitions?